# Troubles with Javascript quiz

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add at least two possible correct answers and don't seem to be able to. Below is the code for the JavaScript and I can post the html if needed. Is what I am trying to do possible? If so, how should I proceed?

```
var questions = [];

questions.push({
    q: "Rate your custard making skills from 1-5.",
    a: "1",
    b: "2",
    c: "3",
    answer: "b"
});

questions.push({
    q: "what is question two?",
    a: "answer one.",
    b: "answer two.",
    c: "answer three.",
    answer: "b"
});

var i = 0;
var answers = [];

window.onload = function() {
    var n = document.getElementById('next');
    n.onclick = next;
    loadNext();
};

function next() {
    var aa = document.getElementById('aa');
    var ab = document.getElementById('ab');
    var ac = document.getElementById('ac');
    var ans = null;
    if (i == 0) loadNext();
    else {
        if (aa.checked) ans = "a";
        if (ab.checked) ans = "b";
        if (ac.checked) ans = "c";
        if (ans) {
            answers.push(ans);
            loadNext();
        } else alert("Please Select an answer.");
    }
};

function loadNext() {
    var qq = document.getElementById('qq');
    var qa = document.getElementById('qa');
    var qb = document.getElementById('qb');
    var qc = document.getElementById('qc');
    if (i >= questions.length) endQuiz();
    else {
        qq.innerHTML = questions[i].q;
        qa.innerHTML = questions[i].a;
        qb.innerHTML = questions[i].b;
        qc.innerHTML = questions[i].c;
        i++;
        document.getElementById('aa').checked = false;
        document.getElementById('ab').checked = false;
        document.getElementById('ac').checked = false;
    }
};

function endQuiz() {
    var score = 0;
    for (var j = 1; j < questions.length; j++)
        if (answers[j] == questions[j].answer)
            score++;
    score *= 2;
    alert("You Scored: " + score);
};
```

Comment: Would you mind creating a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with all the related code?

Comment: I'm not sure, but shouldn't question array be surrounded by [] instead of {} ? (when adding elements/using push)

Comment: In the first object that you push to the questions array there is two properties named `b` and no property named `a`.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld There is nothing wrong with pushing javascript objects `{}` inside an array `[]`.

Comment: @blex. No I get that. But I just somewhat guessed (aren't able to test anything for the moment) that the comparision would fail when you use an array of js-objects but now I looked closer and I see that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: The two properties named b are trying to find a way around it. I tried it with an A it still didn't work. Blex, I can't work out ho9w to use the Fiddle. Thanks for the quick answers.

Comment: @user3408212 http://jsfiddle.net/BwG6L/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have the same property 'b' more than once.

Change the answer to be an array:

```
questions.push({
    q: "Rate your custard making skills from 1-5.",
    a: "1",
    b: "2",
    c: "3",
    answer: ["a", "b"],
    scores: [1, 2]
});
```

Change `next` function to fill the answers array:

```
function next() {
    var aa = document.getElementById('aa');
    var ab = document.getElementById('ab');
    var ac = document.getElementById('ac');
    var ans = [];                           // <-- here
    if (i == 0) loadNext();
    else {
        if (aa.checked) ans.push("a");      // <-- here
        if (ab.checked) ans.push("b");      // <-- here
        if (ac.checked) ans.push("c");      // <-- here
        if (ans.length > 0) {               // <-- here
            answers.push(ans);
            loadNext();
        } else alert("Please Select an answer.");
    }
};
```

Change the verification function to compare question-answers arrays:

```
function endQuiz() {
    var score = 0;
    var correct;
    for (var j = 1; j < questions.length; j++) {
        correct = answers[j].length == questions[j].answer.length;
        if(correct) {
            for(var an=0;an<questions[j].length;an++) {
                if (answers[j][an] != questions[j].answer[an]){
                    correct = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(correct) {
            score++;
        }
    }
    score *= 2;
    alert("You Scored: " + score);
};
```

### Edit:

If I understand correctly, you want to set a score for each possible choice separately. If that's the case, you can, for example, do the following:

Add a `scores` array to the question object which maps a score for a choice, here a=1, b=2:

```
questions.push({
    q: "Rate your custard making skills from 1-5.",
    a: "1",
    b: "2",
    c: "3",
    answer: ["a", "b"],
    scores: [1, 2]
});
```

Change the verification function to add scores depending on the choices:

```
function endQuiz() {
    var score = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < questions.length; j++) {
        for(var an=0;an<questions[j].answer.length;an++) {
            var ansIndex = answers[j].indexOf(questions[j].answer[an]);
            if(ansIndex > -1) {
                score += questions[j].scores[an];
            }
        }
    }
    score *= 2;
    alert("You Scored: " + score);
};
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BwG6L/2/)

Comment: Hmm, that has almost worked, it still gives 2 points on every option fopr some reason.

Comment: I didn't see that. Thank you. :) You are worth 10 Camels. :)